# Which index should be used in prefix,suffix and infix searches?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've created a table to test text searching:

```
CREATE TABLE test (id integer Primary key, the_text varchar(15));
```

Then inserted random values:

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES (generate_series(1,10000000),md5(random()::varchar(15)));
```

I want to use prefix,suffix and infix searches in this table. It's said that using btree index with text_pattern_ops is better for prefix searches,but btree doesn't work much on infix searches like `LIKE %word%`. I was advised to use pg_trgm index. Should I use two different indexes in this situation?

Comment: Have you actually tested that solution? There are too many factors here to provide a simple yes/no answer.

Comment: Depends partly on how much RAM you have and your read vs write load. More indexes = slower writes, and more pressure on memory for cache. OTOH, a simple b-tree will often do a better job for prefix search because it's much more compact and efficient than a GIN or GiST index using `pg_trgm`. Same goes for a b-tree using string reversing for suffix search ... "it depends".